# Cannot connect signal from base class

Tags: c++, qt

When I try to connect a BASE class signal, Qt tells me the signal does not exists on the DERIVED class.

Why is that? How can I tell connect to use the BASE class?

```
namespace MyNamespace 
{

void register(Derived* derived)
{
    // ERROR MSG
    // QObject::connect: No such signal MyNamespace::Derived::baseSignal()

    QObject::connect( derived, SIGNAL(baseSignal()), 
                      foo,     SLOT(fooSlot())); 
}

class Base : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

signals:
    void baseSignal();
};

class Derived : public QObject,
                public Base
{
    Q_OBJECT

signals:
    void derivedSignal();
};

} // namespace MyNamespace
```

Comment: If I cast the sender as Base * in connect() I get the same error.

Comment: Derived contains derivedSignal(), not baseSignal(). You are telling Qt to connect to baseSignal() but passing a Derived as the object where it should look for that function. What happens if you pass a Base * to register()?

Comment: I tried to compile it. There was a warning message which tells me that Derive should not inherited from `QObject`, because base is already inherited from that.

Comment: If I cast the sender as Base * in connect() I get the same error.

Comment: And register is a keyword, so you should find another word.

Comment: Why are you repeating yourself? I asked what happens if you passed a Base * to register(), not connect()

Comment: @underscore same error

Comment: @p.i.g this is just an example. Not the real name of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be much better in this form:

```
namespace MyNamespace 
{

class Base : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

signals:
    void baseSignal();
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    Q_OBJECT

signals:
    void derivedSignal();
};

void registerX( Derived* derived )
{
    QObject::connect( derived, SIGNAL(baseSignal()), foo, SLOT(fooSlot()));
}

} // namespace MyNamespace
```

As [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8578657/qobject-multiple-inheritance) says you shall not inherit QObject multiple times.

Comment: Agreed. Base and derived should not derive both from QObject.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is that you're multiply deriving `Derived` from `QObject`: you derive from it directly *and* through the `Base` class. Don't do that, since Qt doesn't support multiple derivation from `QObject`, not even virtual derivation.

The second and subsequent `QObject` bases are ignored by the `QObject` system. Thus, to the `QObject` machinery, the `Derived` class *only* derives from `QObject`, and not from `Base` - thus it doesn't know about `baseSignal`. As they well should be, since the support of multiple `QObject` derivation would incur runtime overheads - and in any case, you'd need to virtually inherit `QObject`, and you didn't even do that!

At the very minimum, if you expected such to work, your code would need to look as follows:

```
class Base : public virtual QObject { ... };
class Derived : public Base, public QObject { ... };
```

... but Qt doesn't support that.

You'd have been luckier if you wrote the `Derived` class to inherit the base class first:

```
class Base : public QObject { ... };
class Derived : public Base, public QObject { ... };
```

This would have worked, although the second `QObject` base would be pointless and ignored by the `QObject` machinery.