# Qt multiple inheritance ambiguous base class

Tags: c++, qt, multiple-inheritance

So, my class hierarchy looks something like this:

```
     QObject  QGraphicsPolygonItem
           \  /
            \/
          CBubble
            /\
           /  \
 CListBubble  CSingleLinkBubble
           \  /
            \/
       CActionBubble
```

The reason I'm doing multiple inheritance is because I have another bubble that is a CListBubble (LB), but not a CSingleLinkBubble (SB).

The error I receive is "CBubble is an ambiguous base of CActionBubble".

- I've tried the virtual tag on one or both of them.
- I've tried adding "virtual CBubble" to CActionBubble.
- I've tried changing to "public virtual CBubble" in LB and SB, but that causes issues in all bubbles that inherit from them.

I could forego CListBubble entirely and copy/pasta the code, but that goes against all my instincts. I could try to refactor this to use the decorator pattern, but that seems like a lot of unnecessary work for this one case.

Any help or suggestions are much appreciated.
Thanks.

EDIT:
I apologize, should have read the MCVE rules.
Note - I just typed this up now, so hopefully there aren't any syntax issues, but I assume it gets the point across.

clistbubble.h

```
// header guard
#include "cbubble.h"

class CListBubble : public CBubble
{
public:
    CListBubble(const QPointF & pos, QGraphicsItem *parent = 0);

    // data members/methods
};
```

clistbubble.cpp

```
#include "clistbubble.h"

CListBubble(const QPointF & pos, QGraphicsItem *parent)
  : CBubble(pos, parent) // rest of base member initialization
{
       // other stuff for this type of bubble
}

// Other methods
```

The header for CSingleLinkBubble is equivalent in all but members and methods.

cactionbubble.h

```
// header guard
#include "csinglelinkbubble.h"
#include "clistbubble.h"

class CActionBubble : public virtual CSingleLinkBubble, public virtual CListBubble
{
public:
    CActionBubble(const QPointF & pos, QGraphicsItem *parent);

    // data members/methods
};
```

cactionbubble.cpp

```
#include "cactionbubble.h"

CActionBubble(const QPointF & pos, QGraphicsItem *parent)
  : CSingleLinkBubble(pos, parent), CListBubble(pos, parent) // rest of base member initialization
{
       // other stuff for this type of bubble
}
```

I'm concerned that the issue lies in the constructor of CActionBubble where both parent classes are called. However both calls are necessary and would happen anyway if I implemented a default ctor.

The error points me to the place I attempt to new a CActionBubble.
"CBubble is an ambiguous base of CActionBubble"

I also forgot to mention that CBubble inherits from QObject so I can implement signals and slots. I read something awhile back that multiple inheritance with QObject is not possible. Could it be that this is the actual issue, and the error just points one layer below?

Comment: *Where* do you get the error? Can you please show us the code (preferably a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))? Is that the *complete* and *only* error message from the compiler? Please include the *complete* and *unedited* build log.

Comment: The usual solution is the third one you mentioned, why it causes issues in the other classes that inherit from them is another matter to be cleared.

Comment: Your picture corresponds to the third option **only**. The first two options correspond to having **two** `CBubble` instances in each `CActionBubble`. `but that causes issues in all bubbles that inherit from them.` Yes, that's how stuff works in C++. You need to deal with it.

Comment: "refactor this to use the decorator pattern" This could work but I suspect (not sure) this will come to the same "issues in all bubbles that inherit from them" in a different wrap. The issues are not here because of Stroustrup's whims, they are inherent in the MI design, no matter how you implement it.

Comment: @n.m. Ok, could you please elaborate a little on how I should deal with it?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yes, that is the only error aside from some unused variable warnings in methods I haven't finished stubbing out yet.

Comment: Alright, so it seems like I need to inherit virtually all the way through. And make sure that subclasses scope their methods appropriately. Is this correct?

Comment: Show the issues you have...

Comment: You cannot inherit from QObject through multiple base classes. [See this question for why](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8578657/qobject-multiple-inheritance).

Comment: Well, thanks for the help guys. I decided to take the advice given to me by my professor, "if you are using multiple inheritance, you probably need to rethink your approach." I did, and came to the conclusion that my two "list bubbles" need to be handled differently anyway, (one requires a custom QAbstractListModel). So, thanks again, but I'm using a different approach. :)