# QT C++ Connect signals from derived classes

Tags: c++, qt, multiple-inheritance

I am working on a class that has two parent classes:

GetSetInterface which derives QObject and
QSpinBox(which derives QObject aswell)
And I Call it SpinBoxInterface

```
class GetSetInterface : public QObject
class SpinBoxInterface : public QSpinBox, public GetSetInterface
```

In the constructor of `SpinBoxInterface` I am trying to connect signal `QSpinBox::valueChanged(int)` to the signal `GetSetInterface::sendInfo(int, QVariant)`, and here comes a problem:

When I write (of course in `SpinBoxInterface` class)

```
connect(this, QOverload<int>::of(&SpinBoxInterface::valueChanged), this, [=](int value){
        emit sendInfo(TYPE_ANYCHANGE, value);
    });
```

I Get an error `non-static member 'connect' found in multiple base-class subobjects of type 'QObject'`,

However, when I write

```
GetSetInterface::connect(this, QOverload<int>::of(&SpinBoxInterface::valueChanged), this, [=](int value){
        emit sendInfo(TYPE_ANYCHANGE, value);
    });
```

I get an error
`ambigious conversion from derived class 'AxisSpinBox' to base class 'const QObject'`. As long as I understand the first error ('connect found in multiple base-classes'), the second one feels weird, as GetSetInterface::connect has only one parent class, from where to get definition of connect - and it is only one QObject.

`#define TYPE_ANYCHANGE 0` is used in a methods above

Comment: You probably want virtual inheritance and have only one `QObject`.

Comment: @Jarod42 I have tried to change `class GetSetInterface : public QObject` to `class GetSetInterface: virtual public QObject` and it didn't help

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if multiple inheritance from `QObject` simply doesn't work. Are you sure you need to do it? Would encapsulation work instead?

Comment: I needed to do it because I am working on multiple QWidgets lists (ComboBox, LineEdit, SpinBox, DoubleSpinBox) and also I want to have a common type of interface for data in/out, so I can store it in QVector<GetSetInterface*> and just throw GetSetInterface::set and ::get on them. It seems to work with casting 'this' to 'QSpinBox*' in the SpinBoxInterface constructor(very weird for me, but works)

Comment: @JarMan I could probably use composition, the other case with making QObject in one base class 'private' doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I like the composition idea from this answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/68376543/487892](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68376543/487892)